# Colorbar is empty when saving figure as a tiff or jpeg

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot some temperature data over a grayscale image, with the temperature data shown using a colorscale.  I've been able to do so by overlaying a partially-transparent array with the temperature data over the image data.  The problem comes when I try to save it as a tiff (or jpeg).  While the colorbar (for the temperature data) shows up exactly as intended in the Matlab figure, when I save it as a tiff, the colorbar comes up empty (solid white).  Any ideas?

```
figure
imagesc(xlims, ylims, image_data)
set(gca,'YDir','normal');
colormap(gray)
title(title)
xlabel('xlabel')
ylabel('ylabel')
hold on
axis equal
axis tight

%Skip lines of code where I build my temperature array (T) here

%Force a single pixel to 2200
T(1,1)=2200;

%Remove any data below 1000
T(T<1000)=0;

%   Establish Transparency Mask for Temperature Data
transp = T~=0;  %   Binary matrix highlighting where temp data exists

%   Overlay Temp Data on Background Image
imagesc(xlims, ylims, T,'AlphaData',transp)

%   Create Colormaps and Combine Them
%   Note:  Assumes no overlap between background image values and temp data 
%   (highest value in background image is 73)

cmap1 = colormap(gray(73));
cmap2 = colormap(gray(999-73)); 
cmap3 = colormap(jet(2200-999));

cmap = [cmap1; cmap2; cmap3];

%   Apply Combined Colormap to Figure
colormap(cmap)

%   Add and Modify colorbar
h = colorbar;
set(h,'YLim',[1000 2200])    %   Reduces Range of Colorbar to show only Temp Data
ylabel(h,'Temperature, Kelvin')

print(gcf, '-dtiff', 'filename');
```

When saved the colorbar looks like this:

[image: Empty colorbar]

In the Matlab figure it looks fine:

[image: Regular colorbar]

UPDATE: I had a bit of old code that I had done something kind of similar on and went line by line looking at differences.  For some reason, having the figure visible matters?  If I change

```
figure
```

to

```
figure ('visible','off');
```

the whole thing works.  Still curious as to why????

Comment: Please consider adding a screenshot to your resulting Matlab figure as well as the one where the colorbar comes up empty (solid white) so that community members can look at these and understand your problem better.

Comment: Thanks!  Just did as suggested!

Comment: This probably has to do with the renderer for the figure and issues when printing to a file. Since you have transparency, your renderer `get(gcf, 'Renderer')` is going to be `opengl`. I'm guessing that MATLAB keeps the renderer as `painters` if the figure isn't visible. Maybe try `print(gcf, '-dtiff', 'filename', '-painters')`

Comment: Specifying '-painters' does fix the colorbar issue.  However, my background image then becomes solid black.  It looks like I may be stuck not having the figure visible.  Not necessarily a problem, just an extra little pain.